# Excel - How can I shorten this formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote a formula which exceeds 8192 characters and I really need to reach the result of the formula. Actually it is repetetive calculation for different conditions. I'm sure when you see the formula you will get the idea. But there is short explanation below:

1. There are 10 different sources and regarding choosen source formula should work.
2. Regarding choosen currency I need to get result of related calculation.

Right now it is 10.290 chars.

Since this is my first question and I'm kinda new on Excel any help would be appreciated.

*Expected result need to be shown on "unit price" column and different for each item.

---

```
=IFERROR(IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$I29*core!$N$2+core!$I29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29*core!$N$3+core!$I29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$I29/core!$N$2+core!$I29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";(core!$I29/core!$N$3+core!$I29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29/core!$N$3*core!$g29);IF(core!$H29="USD";(core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29);IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;""))))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=2;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$K29+core!$K29*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$K29*core!$N$2+core!$K29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$K29*core!$N$3+core!$K29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=2;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$K29/core!$N$2+core!$K29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$K29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$K29+core!$K29*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$K29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$K29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=2;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$K29/core!$N$3+core!$K29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$K29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$K29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$K29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F$29+core!$K29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g$29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$K29+core!$K29*core!$F29+core!$K29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=3;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$M29+core!$M29*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$M29*core!$N$2+core!$M29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$M29*core!$N$3+core!$M29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=3;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$M29/core!$N$2+core!$M29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$M29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$M29+core!$M29*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$M29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$M29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=3;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$M29/core!$N$3+core!$M29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$M29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$M29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$M29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$M29+core!$M29*core!$F29+core!$M29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=4;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$O29+core!$O29*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$O29*core!$N$2+core!$O29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$O29*core!$N$3+core!$O29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=4;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$O29/core!$N$2+core!$O29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$O29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$O29+core!$O29*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$O29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$O29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=4;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$O29/core!$N$3+core!$O29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$O29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$O29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$O29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$O29+core!$O29*core!$F29+core!$O29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=5;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Q29+core!$Q29*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Q29*core!$N$2+core!$Q29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Q29*core!$N$3+core!$Q29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=5;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Q29/core!$N$2+core!$Q29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Q29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Q29+core!$Q29*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Q29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$Q29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=5;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Q29/core!$N$3+core!$Q29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Q29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Q29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$Q29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Q29+core!$Q29*core!$F29+core!$Q29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=6;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$S29+core!$S29*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$S29*core!$N$2+core!$S29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$S29*core!$N$3+core!$S29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=6;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$S29/core!$N$2+core!$S29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$S29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$S29+core!$S29*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$S29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$S29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=6;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$S29/core!$N$3+core!$S29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$S29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$S29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$S29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$S29+core!$S29*core!$F29+core!$S29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=7;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$U29+core!$U29*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$U29*core!$N$2+core!$U29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$U29*core!$N$3+core!$U29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=7;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$U29/core!$N$2+core!$U29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$U29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$U29+core!$U29*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$U29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$U29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=7;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$U29/core!$N$3+core!$U29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$U29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$U29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$U29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$U29+core!$U29*core!$F29+core!$U29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=8;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$W29+core!$W29*core!$F29++core!$W29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$W29*core!$N$2+core!$W29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$W29*core!$N$3+core!$W29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=8;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$W29/core!$N$2+core!$W29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$W29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$W29+core!$W29*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$W29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$W29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=8;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$W29/core!$N$3+core!$W29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$W29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$W29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$W29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$W29+core!$W29*core!$F29+core!$W29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=9;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Y29+core!$Y29*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Y29*core!$N$2+core!$Y29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Y29*core!$N$3+core!$Y29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=9;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Y29/core!$N$2+core!$Y29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Y29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Y29+core!$Y29*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Y29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$Y29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=9;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$Y29/core!$N$3+core!$Y29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Y29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$Y29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$Y29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$Y29+core!$Y29*core!$F29+core!$Y29*core!$g29;"")))))))))));
IF(core!$D$11=10;IF($F15>0;
IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$AA29+core!$AA29*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$AA29*core!$N$2+core!$AA29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$AA29*core!$N$3+core!$AA29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=10;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$AA29/core!$N$2+core!$AA29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$AA29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$AA29+core!$AA29*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$AA29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$AA29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));
IF(core!$D$11=10;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$AA29/core!$N$3+core!$AA29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$AA29/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$AA29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$AA29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$AA29+core!$AA29*core!$F29+core!$AA29*core!$g29;""))))))))))))))))))))
*(core!$G29+1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrYeP.png)

Comment: I suggest moving to a `vba` function/macro for this.

Comment: or breaking the functions down and using a helper column or two.  The added benefit of the helper column(s) include a) Helping you debug and b) making it easier to change/update.

Comment: Any part of the calculation shouldn't be seen by "customer" because with helper column it will show cost, profit margin and taxes. All need to be calculated at once.

Comment: The primary answer to 'how can I shorten' is always 'factor out the repetition'. I'm sure when you see how many bits repeat the same checks, you can fathom how to at least put those into intermediate cells and reference those instead of repeating the expressions, or perhaps to use better functions like `AND()`, `SWITCH()`, etc.

Comment: @Walkman so put the intermediate helpers in hidden cells...?

Comment: That's what I thought but actually I'd like to know is there a way to change repetitive arguments with shorter and unique characters?

Like instead of "core!$" argument can we put "xx"?

Comment: Do you have sample data with expected results. A visualisation of the problem might be easier to read/understand than a formula like this. It might spark some ideas to resolve your issue differently.

Comment: @JvdV image added below the code with link.

Comment: I suspect this could be massively trimmed by using `VLOOKUP` instead of chained `IF` statements, but it would take a while to refactor it to confirm

Comment: Why do you have `IF(core!$D$11=1;` *inside* an `IF(core!$D$11=1;`?  You've already tested whether or not it's true, so it's completely redundant!  Same for `IF($F15>0;`...  There's a lot of code here that does absolutely nothing except pad the length

Comment: This really looks like this should be a table of conditions rather than if statements.  For example, one column of the lookup table would be the values that d11 might be, another for f15, d7, and so on.  There are techniques for looking up in a table with multiple criteria and searching for ranges as well as exact matches.

Comment: Thank you all to show me precious different perspectives. I will check and will let you know about the final state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IFERROR` has the format `IFERROR(Value, Value_if_error)`.  Your `Value` is this:

```
IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="TL";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$I29*core!$N$2+core!$I29*core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29*core!$N$3+core!$I29*core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$3*core!$g29;"")));IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="USD";IF(core!$H29="TL";core!$I29/core!$N$2+core!$I29/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29/core!$N$2*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="USD";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2+core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$3/core!$N$2*core!$g29;"")));IF(core!$D$11=1;IF($F15>0;IF(core!$D$7="EURO";IF(core!$H29="TL";(core!$I29/core!$N$3+core!$I29/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29/core!$N$3*core!$g29);IF(core!$H29="USD";(core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3+core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$N$2/core!$N$3*core!$g29);IF(core!$H29="EURO";core!$I29+core!$I29*core!$F29+core!$I29*core!$g29;""))))))))))));
```

Taking your formula, splitting out the first part of the `IFERROR`, and eliminating the spurious code (i.e. `IF(A=1, IF(B=2, IF(A=1, ALWAYS_TRUE, ALWAYS_FALSE), C), D)` is functionally identical to `IF(A=1, IF(B=2, ALWAYS_TRUE, C), D)`), I then built the following table:

[image: A 3 by 3 of the D7 and H29 values (TL, USD, and EURO) and the formulae for each combination]

The Red, Blue and Green text are Common Terms, present in every formula.

Examining this, and rearranging it slightly, I spot the following patterns:

- When D7 is "USD", Divide by $N$2
- When D7 is "EURO", Divide by $N$3
- When H29 is "USD", Multiply by $N$2
- When H29 is "EURO", Multiply by $N$3

Implicitly, the following rules also exist:

- When D7 is "TL", Divide by 1
- When H29 is "TL", Multiply by 1

I can use a `VLOOKUP` to pick which cells to use, resulting in the form `VLOOKUP(H29,..) * (Common_Terms) / VLOOKUP(D7,..)`

This allows me to rewrite your `Value` as follows:

```
IF(AND(core!$D$11=1,$F15>0), IF(AND(MATCH(core!$D$11,{"TL","USD","EURO","*"},0)<4, MATCH(core!$H$29,{"TL","USD","EURO","*"},0)<4), VLOOKUP(core!H$29,{"USD",core!$N$2;"Euro",core!$N$3;"TL",1},2,FALSE)*(core!$I29 + core!$I29*core!$F29 + core!$I29*core!$g29)/VLOOKUP(core!H$29,{"USD",core!$N$2;"Euro",core!$N$3;"TL",1},2,FALSE), ""), FALSE)
```

Which is a *third* of the length.  You should be able to manage similar optimisation of almost every `IF` condition you have.

More importantly, a *lot* of your repeated (and unnecessary) `IF` conditions are checking if H29 and D7 are "TL"/"USD"/"EUR", or checking that F15>0.  You can eliminate these by making your *outermost* `IF` statement look like this:

```
=IF(AND($F15>0, MATCH(core!$D$7, core!$D$11, {"TL","USD","EURO","*"},0)<4, MATCH(core!$H$29, {"TL","USD","EURO","*"},0)<4), ALL_THREE_CONTITIONS_ARE_TRUE, "")
```

Comment: That answer is something like more tha I can imagine. Thank you for your effort at first. I will check and let you know asap.